# Waiting for restore metadata - Percona Operator for MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm, database-backups, percona

**Description**
Hello am trying to restore backup from minio to a new mongodb cluster deployed on kubernetes using Percona Operator. But am getting Waiting for restore metadata which isn’t changing seems to be stuck in that loop.

**This is my configurations.
**

```
{{- if .Values.backup.restore.enabled }}
apiVersion: psmdb.percona.com/v1
kind: PerconaServerMongoDBRestore
metadata:
  name: mongodb-restore-test
spec:
  clusterName: mongodb-psmdb-db
  backupSource:
    type: logical
    destination: s3://mongodb-backup/2024-01-16T17:45:21Z
    s3:
      credentialsSecret: minio-s3-creds-restore
      region: us-west-004
      bucket: mongodb-backup
      endpointUrl: http://minio.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000
      prefix: mongodb-backup
{{ end }}
```

**Restore the cluster from a previously saved backup.**

This seems to be working well with no problems as described in the percona operator I tested and the restore did work.[text](https://docs.percona.com/percona-operator-for-mongodb/backups-restore.html?h=rest)

What I want to achieve is to be able to restore the back up to the new cluster in the event we have to do a Disaster Recovery. This is described here in the documentations [text](https://docs.percona.com/percona-operator-for-mongodb/backups-restore-to-new-cluster.html)

This is how my configuration look

`{{- if .Values.backup.restore.enabled }} apiVersion: psmdb.percona.com/v1 kind: PerconaServerMongoDBRestore metadata: name: mongodb-restore-test spec: clusterName: mongodb-psmdb-db backupSource: type: logical destination: s3://mongodb-backup/2024-01-16T17:45:21Z s3: credentialsSecret: minio-s3-creds-restore region: us-west-004 bucket: mongodb-backup endpointUrl: http://minio.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000 prefix: mongodb-backup {{ end }}`

Results

[image]

[image]

```
2024-01-16T18:53:13.874Z    INFO    Restore state changed   {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "47e51140-f232-4a48-aef6-b3d694c6d521", "previous": "", "current": "waiting"}
2024-01-16T18:53:24.952Z    INFO    Starting restore    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "1f97dd4e-30a0-4e9c-9015-aa85d376886c"}
2024-01-16T18:53:24.000+0000 D [resync] got physical restores list: 0
2024-01-16T18:53:24.000+0000 D [resync] got backups list: 1
2024-01-16T18:53:25.000+0000 D [resync] bcp: 2024-01-16T17:45:21Z.pbm.json
2024-01-16T18:53:25.150Z    INFO    Restore state changed   {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "1f97dd4e-30a0-4e9c-9015-aa85d376886c", "previous": "waiting", "current": "requested"}
2024-01-16T18:53:25.190Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "2b428410-f5b0-4e56-88c1-22dc3f2b8dd2", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:53:30.188Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "666a18d6-2c47-488b-94b7-4062c27d9c13", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:53:35.226Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "f0086c68-df5b-4316-974d-962954246b3f", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:53:40.279Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "b53f3b12-0310-44ff-8248-99b081116fb3", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:53:45.326Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "3e84240f-b834-48d5-bc7c-d35ea8f0c40e", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:53:50.382Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "d65505da-1f8c-40a6-9fac-55616232f2a1", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:53:55.422Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "a5c1b8e0-d6ba-4255-afb1-67a0826b8dd6", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:00.478Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "d57992c5-d2af-4f45-a7df-95185add24f5", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:05.738Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "9717b110-748e-4cb6-a19b-f6e71e81e0e4", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:10.859Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "06d4eb4f-367a-4eb8-a52e-3d7c5661aac6", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:15.900Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "37706f66-12eb-44e3-9192-e2b0c02a6485", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:20.938Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "cfeebf60-ae04-433c-ba84-d22282236674", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:25.975Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "7d679192-0c99-4085-bfe9-fcb3b91e1364", "PBM name": "2024-01-16T18:53:25.139584352Z", "restore": "mongodb-restore-test", "backup": ""}
2024-01-16T18:54:31.031Z    INFO    Waiting for restore metadata    {"controller": "perconaservermongodbrestore-controller", "object": {"name":"mongodb-restore-test","namespace":"testrestore"}, "namespace": "testrestore", "name": "mongodb-restore-test", "reconcileID": "0c274f98-4d44-4235-81b5-3c19e6345846",
```